# Scikit-Learn n_jobs Multiprocessing Locked To One Core

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Trying to use gridsearch CV with multiple jobs via the n_jobs argument and I can see using htop that they're all launched and running but they all get stuck/assigned on the same core using 25% each (I'm using a 4 core machine). I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 and I'm running the latest master pulled from github. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, there's a note on the svm page that if you enable verbose settings multiprocessing may break. Disabling verbose fixed it

Comment: Can you provide a link or be more specific?